# PyCharm - convert every string to fstring automatically

Tags: python, intellij-idea, ide, pycharm

I use f-strings very often and I always forget to prefix it with `f`. Is it possible to tell `PyCharm` to automatically add `f` before any string when it's being created?

I was considering Live Template but I don't want to do anything except writing quotes.

As @PM 2Ring pointed out, it could be inefficient so maybe the way is a shortcut. For example, if I press f.e. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, the string become an f-strings.

Comment: Are you _sure_ you really want to do this? Using f-strings when you only need normal string literals would be rather inefficient.

Comment: @PM2Ring You're right, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 4):

This feature has been implemented in version PyCharm 2020.2. Official Issue Page [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-42700).

Comment: P.S. Just installed and tested.